# Cannot install latest version of Grafana with apt-get

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get, grafana

I am having problems installing Grafana with apt-get. I am following these instructions:
http://docs.grafana.org/installation/debian/#apt-repository

I added the repository, and ran `apt-get update & apt-get install grafana`. What I got installed was the old version 2.6.0.

I tried checking `apt-cache policy grafana` and i got:

```
grafana:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.0+dfsg-3+b1
  Version table:
     2.6.0+dfsg-3+b1 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

For some reason it is still trying to install from old repository. Then I tried to check what packages does the grafana-repo contain (https://serverfault.com/questions/252333/list-all-packages-from-a-repository-in-ubuntu-debian). And what I get is a list like this:

```
grep Package /var/lib/apt/lists/packagecloud.io_grafana_stable_debian_dists_stretch_InRelease

 ...
 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e 0 main/binary-arm64/Packages
 4059d198768f9f8dc9372dc1c54bc3c3 14 main/binary-arm64/Packages.bz2
 30309128fc2d8ec104240ded2f49f555 20 main/binary-arm64/Packages.gz
 ...
```

I have no clue is that correct or not. Should I just give up with apt-get and install this thing with dpkg?

Answer (score 0):

The Grafana apt repository only supports ARMv7 and ARM32 builds[1](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/debian/), you likely have a Raspberry Pi 1 or Zero which requires ARMv6[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications).

Solutions could be:

1. Use the (4 months old but newer than Debian) package from [fg2it](https://github.com/fg2it/grafana-on-raspberry), instructions [here](https://www.circuits.dk/install-grafana-influxdb-raspberry/) - see what you're missing in the [changelog](http://docs.grafana.org/guides/whats-new-in-v5-3/)
2. build from source, likely extremely slow. Instructions at [grafana's website](http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/)